# Can't scroll in view android/xamarin

Tags: c#, android, mobile, xamarin

I'm trying to get my view to be scrollable and I've google and it seems that I need to have a `<ScrollView` that wraps my `Linear Layout`.

I've done that but still can't scroll. What am I missing?

http://pastebin.com/HhXyvTxR

Answer (score 0):

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
   <LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:scrollbars="vertical"
   android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true">
   </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

It should be like this

Comment: Still can't scroll. Tried like above